# How to play a diamond note on guitar?

Tags: guitar, notation, technique, harmonics

[image]
[Source](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/f/ff/IMSLP427906-PMLP54762-Tarrega_F-Capricho_Arabe+mid.pdf)

Here it is written in diamond notes in the first measure. How should one play them on guitar and also what do they indicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diamond notes indicate [harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_harmonic). Basically you generate a note by lightly touching the string an integer fraction of the way down (like 1/3, 1/4, 1/5 etc.) so that instead of vibrating with the frequency length of the string it vibrates with the fractional length.

In this specific example this is **natural harmonic** played by placing finger above 7th fret (see text above the score) of three bass strings.

There is some more useful information in a good answer to this [related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20810/guitar-harmonics-notation-in-tabluature) on this forum.

The Wikipedia article referenced above gives some additional information on ways to play harmonics on the guitar which don't apply to other stringed instruments:

> **Tapped harmonics**
>
> Tapped harmonics were popularized by Eddie van Halen. This technique
> is an extension of the tapping technique. The note is fretted as
> usual, but instead of striking the string the excitation energy
> required to sound the note is achieved by tapping at a harmonic nodal
> point. The tapping finger bounces lightly on and off the fret. The
> open string technique can be extended to artificial harmonics. For
> instance, for an octave harmonic (12-fret nodal point) press at the
> third fret, and tap the fifteenth fret, as 12 + 3 = 15.

and

> **Pinch harmonics**
>
> A pinch harmonic (also known as squelch picking, pick harmonic or
> squealy) is a guitar technique to achieve artificial harmonics in
> which the player's thumb or index finger on the picking hand slightly
> catches the string after it is picked,[10] canceling (silencing) the
> fundamental frequency of the string, and letting one of the overtones
> dominate. This results in a high-pitched sound which is particularly
> discernible on an electrically amplified guitar as a "squeal".

Comment: Check out Jaco's harmonics in Birdland.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Brian's answer: the instruction on top at that point is 'ar. 7'. Meaning play the 'armonic at the 7th fret. (Could well have been coined by a Brummie!).

The diamond headed notes are the *original* notes, not the ones which will sound. Here, they are the bottom 3 strings, open (D-tuned bottom string). Making an A5 'chord', due to that being the 2nd partial/3rd harmonic.

Simple way to play - place a barre finger just touching the 3 strings over the 7th fret, pluck with 3 fingers from other hand. No need to move them off quickly after they sound - like a lot of players believe.